# Nuxtjs app stops immediately when start with pm2

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, pm2

I am trying to run a nuxtjs app using `pm2` however, the app exits immediately, and I could not get useful info from pm2 log:

```
2|frontend_nuxt  | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chdir '����' -> '/var/www/frontend_nuxt/releases/20210831071742'
2|frontend_nuxt  |     at wrappedChdir (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/does_own_process_state:112:14)
2|frontend_nuxt  |     at process.chdir (node:internal/worker:100:5)
2|frontend_nuxt  |     at /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:298:13
2|frontend_nuxt  |     at wrapper (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16)
2|frontend_nuxt  |     at next (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/waterfall.js:96:20)
2|frontend_nuxt  |     at /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/internal/onlyOnce.js:12:16
2|frontend_nuxt  |     at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/lib/Utility.js:186:13)
2|frontend_nuxt  |     at WriteStream.emit (node:events:394:28)
2|frontend_nuxt  |     at node:internal/fs/streams:72:16
2|frontend_nuxt  |     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:185:23)
```

The nuxtjs app it self can start without issue.
I have no idea how to debug this error, or how to get more useful details, any idea?

Comment: Does it run locally? Did you followed the instructions here? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-pm2

Comment: yes, it runs locally, however, running `npm run build` then `pm2 start` then `pm2 status` and I can see it with status `errored` and the log as in the question above.

Answer (score 2):

using `npm2 show id` I found that the script path was not updated.
so, i just had to:

```
pm2 delete frontend_nuxt && pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

and all is well.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer when you'll be able to.

Comment: You should be able after some time. Check the info given on hover.

Comment: Yes, tomorrow I would be able to.